# I want to create an alert for the first time an app is opened

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to create an alert for the first time an app is opened on the device but I am having some trouble with the code. this is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated

```
    // alert first time app is opened
    // making of alert

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Navigation", message: "Tap Right Hand Side of Screen For Next Quote, Left Hand Side To Go Back", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //add ok button
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

    // detect if first launch
    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launcedBefore")
    if launchedBefore {
    }
    else {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }
```

this is where I am trying to place the code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

Comment: put the alert in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in AppDelegate

Comment: "but I am having some trouble with the code" What trouble exactly?

Comment: "launcedBefore" != "launchedBefore"

Comment: could you elaborate what is your trouble?

Comment: the alert is not coming up when the app is launched. and i am not sure what is wrong with the code

Comment: @iasla, can you share the ViewController code, where you are trying to present an alert, please? Your code looks OK except the typo in keys values, but it should present an alert even in that case.

Comment: @livenplay, sorry I am new to coding and not sure what you mean by ViewController code. I have updated the question with where I am trying to place the code. Hopefully this is what you mean

Comment: @iasla looks like this viewcontroller does not execute, make sure that it has first entry point

Comment: i found the solution, i had to put the code into viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the `launcedBefore` key
Change it to:

```
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try it in AppDelegate you have to present the alert in `window?.rootViewController?`

```
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Any message", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("OK Pressed")
            }
var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
            }
alertController.addAction(okAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Check the value(true or false) you are getting in `let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launcedBefore")`. Show alert depends on the `bool` value.